# How to add two parents to a single child object in blender?

Tags: animation, three.js

I have a car tire and I want two different bones to control it's rotation and and turning respectively.For that I want to make the tire parent to both the bones.Please tell me the way to a two bones parent to tire.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about 3D modeling.

Answer (score 1):

An object can only have one parent. In the example you give, you want one wheel bone to control the wheel. This bone would be animated to rotate on its Y-axis, this bone is then parented to a steering bone that will "turn" the wheel bone, but does not directly move the wheel mesh.

[image: example rigged wheel]

[image]

Comment: This rotates the wheel but doesn't turn the wheel?

Comment: Please can you explain a bit in detail how to do it.

Comment: @VedantBhosale Two bones - one rotates the wheel as it rolls on the ground, the other steers the wheel. I have added a link to an example blend.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: So you have connected vertical bone's head to horizontal's tail using offset in edit mode and connected horizontal bone's head to tire using the same.Am I correct?

Comment: One last question.How to connect the head of the horizontal bone to the wheel.I am unable to do that.I think I may be following wrong procedure.